# Create Robot in UiPath Orchestrator

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-robot, uipath-api

I have been working with UiPath Studio to automate workflows and was successful.
Now I want to create a UiPath Orchestrator Robot to deploy on my machine.

1. I create a machine in UiPath Orchestrator, but while creating a robot, I am not able to find the **Password** field option. Also attached a screen shot.

[image: As shown in the image there is no Password Field]

2. At a time of creating a **JOB**, robot name is not displayed. (The robot is created and it is also added to Environment tab) Also attached a screen shot

[image: As shown in img i.e no robot name showing]

Answer (score 4):

Only unattended robots require a username and password. Or at least, attended ones don't.

> I am not able to find the Password field option

A user with access to the physical machine kicks off a an attended robot. Since they must be logged in already to kick the process off, UiPath has no need to know the username and password required to log into the computer.

### Unattended Robots in UiPath

If you're looking for the password field, you'll need to create an [unattended robot](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Create-your-first-RPA-robot-to-UiPath-Orchestrator-tutorial), as opposed to a Studio robot. My understanding is support for Studio and Studio Pro robots is ending.

> At a time of creating a JOB, robot name is not displayed.

Again, I believe this is a manifestation of the fact that the Studio robot is to be triggered manually from the client machine, so a robot from UiPath Orchestrator is not required.

Notice how on this screenshot, the robot type is set to unattended and the requirement to set the Domain\username and password of the client machine appear.

[image]

### Starting the robot

It is when you start the [UiPath process](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-create-a-UiPath-Orchestrator-process-to-run-your-RPA-robots) associated with the unattended robot that the selection of the robot happens. An example of that is here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Before adding a job you need to **upload** (Deploy) a **process** to Orchestrator. I think you already did this in the UiPath Studio with the Deploy button so we skip this.

Now on Orchestrator you need to "create" that process. I know it's a bit confusing as you already have created it. Maybe see this from another view. Like you could have multiple server. And one process might be running with different settings on each of that servers.

So all you need to do is clicking the **+Button** on the **Processes window**. Here select your process and your environment. If you have no environment, you need to create this before.

[image: UiPath processes window]

Answer (score 1):

> I create a machine in UiPath Orchestrator, but while creating a robot, I am not able to find the Password field option. Also attached a screen shot.

With the introduction of Unattended Robots in Modern folders, scheduling of processes towards Studio robots is no longer possible.

Since Studio Robots can only start processes via Studio or Robot Agent (UiPath Assistant in 20.4), Orchestrator no longer needs the user password.

I know it is not an obvious connection, but you can find more information on this thread:
https://forum.uipath.com/t/studio-scheduling-will-be-disabled-thoughts-pending-jobs/200090

> At a time of creating a JOB, robot name is not displayed. (The robot is created and it is also added to Environment tab) Also attached a screen shot

Indeed, for the same reason as point 1, you will not see Studio robots in the list of robots available for a job.
You will only see Non Production or Unattended robots.

Answer (score 1):

You will not see the Studio type Robots while running a job, change the Robot type to Unattended or Non Production based on the license you have.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I create a machine in UiPath Orchestrator, but while creating a robot, I am not able to find the Password field option.

Ans: Robot connects with your computer to execute process and it needs password of our machine to run the process in unattendent mode, so password option will onlu come if you select the bot type "Unattendent".

Q2.At a time of creating a JOB, robot name is not displayed. (The robot is created and it is also added to Environment tab)

Ans: Make sure during process creation the right environment was selected, double check the Bot has been assigned to the perticular enviromment or not which you are using.